# Wrong ruby version being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get rails running on my mac which is running lion. I'm using rvm and it shows I'm using ruby 1.9.2p312 but when I go to start the server I'm getting an error referencing ruby 1.8 and that rails is not installed even though previous to this error I ran bundle install and it installed everything I needed successfully.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Ok, it seems that the 1.8 error has gone away. Here is the new error and bundle show:

```
bundle exec rails s
/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': no such file to load -- spec (LoadError)
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/anthonyd/Sites/rails/reminders/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'


bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.1.3)
  * actionpack (3.1.3)
  * activemodel (3.1.3)
  * activerecord (3.1.3)
  * activeresource (3.1.3)
  * activesupport (3.1.3)
  * arel (2.2.1)
  * aws-s3 (0.6.2)
  * bbenezech-nested_form (0.0.2)
  * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
  * bootstrap-sass (1.4.0)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.0.21)
  * coffee-rails (3.1.1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.1.3)
  * devise (1.5.2 b303429)
  * diff-lcs (1.1.3)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.2.9)
  * haml (3.1.4)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * hpricot (0.8.5)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * jquery-rails (1.0.19)
  * json (1.6.3)
  * kaminari (0.12.4)
  * mail (2.3.0)
  * mime-types (1.17.2)
  * multi_json (1.0.4)
  * nokogiri (1.5.0)
  * orm_adapter (0.0.5)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.3.5)
  * rack-cache (1.1)
  * rack-mount (0.8.3)
  * rack-pjax (0.5.5)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.1.3)
  * rails_admin (0.0.1 6120ad4)
  * railties (3.1.3)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.11)
  * remotipart (1.0.1)
  * rspec (2.7.0)
  * rspec-core (2.7.1)
  * rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
  * rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
  * sass (3.1.11)
  * sass-rails (3.1.5)
  * sprockets (2.0.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.4)
  * sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.31)
  * warden (1.1.0)
  * xml-simple (1.1.1)

rails s
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18

**ruby -v**
ruby 1.9.2p312 (2011-08-11 revision 32926) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

**RVM Info**:

system:
    uname:       "Darwin Anthony-DeFreitass-MacBook-Pro.local 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin11.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.10.0-pre by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p312"
    date:         "2011-08-11"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin11.2.0"
    patchlevel:   "2011-08-11 revision 32926"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p312 (2011-08-11 revision 32926) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    ruby:         "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin:/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/anthonyd:/Users/anthonyd/imagemagick/bin:/Users/anthonyd/imagemagick/lib:.rvm/scripts/rvm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head:/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Did you have other Ruby installation before install RVM?

Comment: when you install a new Ruby version from RVM the gemset gets empty , so you have to install all gems again. ( bundle install )

Comment: Before RVM I had ruby installed, I think it's referencing the old one in the error below: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8

Comment: I did 'bundle install' and now I get this after trying to start the server:                                                                rails s
/Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': no such file to load -- spec (LoadError)

Comment: ok, there is conflict with your old version of Ruby, you could use the new ruby as the default for your system, doing something like `rvm use 1.9.2p312 --default`  now you will ruby 1.9.2 by default and then you have to install all gems again ( for the new gemset )

Comment: I sugest you to use bundle for run libraries in your new rails installation,

Comment: That's the thing, I've already done rvm use 1.9.2p312 --default and ruby -v is showing that I'm using 1.9.2 but I think somewhere it's being overridden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If using RVM, make sure that in your ~/.bash_profile file the path for rvm comes before the other paths.

For example, put this into your ~/.bash_profile before any PATH declarations:

```
export PATH=:~/.rvm/bin/:~/.rvm/gems/gems/
```

Then the rest of your export declarations which might look like this (this is just an example, you don't need to put it in, I'm just including it so you see how the file might look like, but the above line you definitely need):

```
export PATH=:~/bin/:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/bin:/usr/local/Cellar:/usr/local/sphinx:/usr/sbin:$PATH
```

Finally, if, like me, you ditched RVM and went with rbenv then substitute the first `export PATH` line with this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

These changes should make the system look at your RVM files before the built-in ones in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework`

Good luck.

Comment: export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I see this has been answered but I'd recommend simply typing

`gem install bundler` or `gem update bundler`

It fixes the problem OP had without modifying your Bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run `bundle exec rails s` when using bundle and rvm with different rails versions.

Comment: Thanks but it seems like it doesn't see that anything is installed, it can't find Bundler:                                            bundle exec rails s
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: The newest error is: bundle exec rails s /Users/anthonyd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler 1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': no such file to load -- spec (LoadError) –